# Optimising checkbox method

Tags: c#, winforms

I have five checkboxes contained within a panel (WeekdaysP) on a form. I want it to be that whenever three of these checkboxes are checked, the others are disabled. My current code looks like this:

```cs
private void CheckCBEnabled()
{
    int upToThree = 0;
    if (MondayCB.Checked)
    {
        upToThree++;
    }
    if (TuesdayCB.Checked)
    {
        upToThree++;
    }
    if (WednesdayCB.Checked)
    {
        upToThree++;
    }
    if (ThursdayCB.Checked)
    {
        upToThree++;
    }
    if (FridayCB.Checked)
    {
        upToThree++;
    }
    if (upToThree >= 3)
    {
        WeekDaysP.Enabled = false;
    }
    return;
}
```

Any advice on how I can streamline/optimise the efficiency of the code?

Comment: You can add all the checkboxes in a list. Then check List.Where(c=>c.Checked).Count >= 3. You can also, access the WeekDaysP.Child collection, loop through and find and process all checkboxes and do the same thing. but, I would incline towards having a array/list of bool's bound to each checkbox.(like wpf bindings).

Comment: Also, if you disable the panel, how can user uncheck/change his mind and pick a different day?

Comment: Maybe you can build a collection or a list with CheckBox controls and then loop on them to see Checked status. Your current code is optimized, but no handly because is verbose. Also point that a `void`method doesn't need the `return` specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add to a `List<CheckBox>` and use linq, something like this:

```
    List<CheckBox> weekdayCBs;
    private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        weekdayCBs = new List<CheckBox> { MondayCB, TuesdayCB, WednesdayCB, ThursdayCB, FridayCB };
    }

    private void CheckCBEnabled()
    {
        WeekDaysP.Enabled = weekdayCB.Count(cb => cb.Checked) >= 3;
    }
```

EDIT: As an aside, and this has already been mentioned in comments, you specifically asked for *optimisation*, and your code is close to optimal from a *number of operations* point of view (I can think of a couple of small optimisations, but they'd be almost inconsequential). A rewrite such as the one above provides far greater readability at the expense of a bit of overhead. This is generally a good thing, especially when dealing with user interfaces where tiny optimisations won't be noticed by the user.

Comment: Well WinForms already has such a list. It will be the Child collection of OP's WeekDaysP panel. So we can get away with our own collection.

Comment: @PrateekShrivastava true, but it's not specified if there are other items in this container (eg. additional labels), which complicates casting to inspect the Checked property, which is why I've opted for a separate list.  I was trying to keep it simple to understand - it's a matter of preference, I suppose.

Comment: But, wouldn't this code require a new developer to KNOW that if they add a new checkbox in GUI, they need to remember to add it to the List to. (Agree, that in this scenario its Weekdays so only 5 are possible) but think about generic terms. I would incline towards using the Child collection and casting the checkboxes. May be coz I am more from a WPF mind set - i do not like code behinds.

Comment: Sure, that's definitely a consideration. I more robust implementation would definitely have to consider added checkboxes, non-checkbox controls, abstracting the allowed max selected count into a configuration option, etc. As I said, I was trying to keep it simple to illustrate the Linq.

Answer (score 1):

Make your CheckBoxes subscribe to the **`CheckedChanged`** event using the same event handler (select them all and double-click the event in the Form Designer).

- When the `CheckState` of one of the CheckBoxes changes, the event is raised.
  Verify whether 3 of these Controls are checked and, if the condition is met, disable the CheckBoxes that are not checked.
- If less than 3 are selected, enable those that are eventually disabled (so you can change the selection, if needed).

```
private void checkBoxes_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var checkBoxes = (sender as Control).Parent.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>();
    var checkedCount = checkBoxes.Count(c => c.Checked);

    checkBoxes.ToList().ForEach(c => {
        if (!c.Checked) {
            c.Enabled = checkedCount != 3;
        }
    });
}
```

<sub>If you have other CheckBoxes on that container, move those that are part of this *selection* to their own, separated, container (another Panel), so there's no *confusion*</sub>

Comment: Nice tidy solution which deals with the issue of making changes to the selections if you need to

Comment: Thanks for the advice.